# How to get DataGridView column of signed numeric values to sort correctly?

Tags: c#-4.0

How may I get a DataGridView column of signed numeric values to sort by signed value? Currently ColumnType is DataGridViewTextBoxColumn and ValueType is typeof(System.Single), but sorting is on the absolute rather than signed value, e.g:

```
-2.728
 3.835
 4.132
-4.511
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ignore what ValueType and column type are.

What is the type of the actual objects in the cells (dataGrid[x, y].Value.GetType())? You are probably filling the grid with System.String objects. If you fill the grid with System.Single objects they will be sorted properly.

Another option is to handle the [SortCompare](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.sortcompare.aspx) event.

Comment: I thought I'd checked that I was filling with numbers but then found an overlooked change to strings, to gain format control. Once I'd moved format to the column cell style, I was able to fill with numbers and problem solved. Thanks svinja. One day I hope to find out the purpose of .ValueType :)